# How to use Key Interface for secret key in java?

Tags: java, cryptography

I have a code from [creating base 64 hashes](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java)

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ApiSecurityExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
     String secret = "secret";
     String message = "Message";

     Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
     SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
     sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

     String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
     System.out.println(hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error");
    }
   }
}
```

there is `secret_key` in `sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);`

when I read, it tells use `Key key` an Interface.

how to use it?

Answer (score 4):

The example is doing it wrong, as strings should not be used to store keys.

A secret key should consist of bytes that are unpredictable to an adversary. The most logical method to generate those is to use a random number generator, but you can also generate them from key establishment (Diffie-Hellman), using a key derivation function upon another key, ratchets and many other ways.

A somewhat dangerous method is to generate them from a password. For that you normally use a Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF. Java has direct support for PBKDF2 which can be used for this.

---

So you could create a HMAC key in the following way:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");

SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
// key size can be anything but should default to the hash / MAC output size for HMAC
byte[] hmacKeyData = new byte[mac.getMacLength()];
rng.nextBytes(hmacKeyData);
SecretKey hmacKey = new SecretKeySpec(hmacKeyData, "HMACSHA256");
Arrays.fill(hmacKeyData, (byte) 0x00);
```

However, the following code is shorter, probably more descriptive. It also allows hardware devices to be used later on to implement the `Mac`, although that might be a bit out of your territory.

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
SecretKey hmacKey = kg.generateKey();
```

Finally, if you still want to use a password, then use PKBDF2 and don't forget to store the salt:

```
// you don't want to use a string, as you cannot delete strings in Java
char[] password = {'p', 'a', 's', 's' };
SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[128 / Byte.SIZE];
rng.nextBytes(salt);
int iterations = 1_000_000;

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");

PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, mac.getMacLength() * Byte.SIZE);
SecretKeyFactory pbkdf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
byte[] hmacKeyData = pbkdf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
SecretKey hmacKey = new SecretKeySpec(hmacKeyData, "HMACSHA256");

// clean up secret material
Arrays.fill(password, (char) 0x0000); 
spec.clearPassword();
Arrays.fill(hmacKeyData, (byte) 0x00);
```

As an attacker may have forever to try passwords if he has a MAC to compare the result with, it would be a very good idea to choose a very complex password though; this is why password based encryption generally is not a good idea.

---

`Key` is a generic parent interface used for both `SecretKey`, `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey`. It is used in many classes that represent crypto algorithms as they may be used with any kind of key. For instance `Cipher` can be used for RSA but also for AES. So the implementation just checks at runtime if the correct key is given.

For `Mac` it might as well have been `SecretKey` as a `Mac` is really always a symmetrical algorithm (an asymmetric form of a `Mac` is called a `Signature` after all). Just a HMAC key would not be enough though, as there are also `Mac` algorithms based on block ciphers such as AES (thus requiring a `SecretKey` with algorithm `"AES"`).

For convenience, `SecretKeySpec` also implements `SecretKey`; that way you don't need the `SecretKeyFactory` to create a `SecretKey`. The Java designers kind of forgot about hardware support that *does* require such as factory, but here we are.